# Confused regarding MVC - Where do codes that add target to a UIButton go in MVC?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I am specifically using `XIB` as my `UIView`, and then a `UIViewController` for the controller in between the `(M)odel` and `(V)iew` in `MVC` design pattern, as recommended by Apple..

Should I just connect the first responder outlet to the button outlet in *`Interface Builder`* or should I programmatically add it to the `UIViewController`-based `Swift` class which controls that `XIB` view?

I guess business logic should go in the UIViewController `(C)ontroller` class... but what about regular application logic? I guess add a target to a button would be considered logic.. but '(V)iew' logic...

Comment: Ask your self this simple question - does the view controller need to know "how" an action occurs or does it only care that it took place?  What I mean is, does the controller care that a "button was pressed" or does it care that "some action occurred".  If you decouple the controller from the view, you can make the controller and view re-usable - this is where (IMHO) storyboard workflows fall down and we end up with the "massive view controllers" problem.  Instead, I would use some kind of `protocol` which defines events the view is likely to generate - but that's me

Comment: I don't use storyboards, only custom XIB view (interface builder)... I also use programmatic views. I create reusable cocoa touch classes pretty frequently where the view (UI) logic is in the XIB and the logic functions are in the swift class, then I use a convenience init and reuse it over and over again (very very custom type classes like a presentation modal), etc.

Comment: Massive view controller is not real issue for me, because I do like this -> Parent ViewController --> Table View --> TableViewCell --> ViewController --> CollectionView --> UICollectionViewCell <---- All Embedded. It scrolls very fast, low memory and not much code if using XIB.

Comment: Thanks for the question to ask myself. It's right. You're right.

Comment: @MadProgrammer -- Should business logic go inside the Controller or a service class? I guess you can create service classes which the Controller calls directly??

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I answered this myself... I think it makes sense. Let me know and please mark it correctly if so... when you ask me this question.. it click in my brain.

Comment: The view controller's intention is to coordinate changes between the model and the view.  So it's listening to the model and view and passing on changes which occur between them (based on Apples design concepts).  Some of the business logic may be contained in both the controller and model, depending on your needs and requirements (ie, a controller could be used to provide  tighter requirements over what the model provides, another could delegate that to the model, based on different conditions).  What you want to avoid is coupling the three together to tightly

Comment: You can get a better idea from [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#:~:text=The%20Model%2DView%2DController%20(,objects%20communicate%20with%20each%20other.), but remember, Apple is moving away from this with SwiftUI

Comment: Dave Delong’s [A Better MVC](https://davedelong.com/blog/2017/11/06/a-better-mvc-part-1-the-problems/) (can be found on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfsT6o95shw)) is a helpful way to think of MVC, without throwing the baby with the bathwater. In this opinion, view controllers are considered as part of the “view” (which makes sense ... they are inherently tied to UIKit, primarily dealing with the populating of views and responding to input from the UI), and abstract the “C” of MVC into a separate UI-independent object. This abstracts the business logic out of the view layer.

Comment: @Rob - so like a service or manager class for abstracting the biz logic out of the view layer?

Comment: Yeah, analogous, but one for each view.

Answer (score 0):

[image: User should use a controller, which has view attached, to manipulate data model and update the view of the controller they are using, which is attached. This makes the most sense to me.]

For specificity --> `MODEL` contains the business, application and data structure logic.

The `Controller` can utilize internal functions, classes, structs as well as external '*service*' or '*manager*' classes to manipulate the `MODEL`, which the view should have connected it to it, and thus updates from. Bingo :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer to make the code targets inside XIB classes and make an output interface for the XIB then let the ViewController or whatever view conform to It. This help Make the reusable XIB much easier to use

If we depend on The Parent View to add the target methods, so every parent will use the XIB should make Its own method, and the Parent does not have the usage guidelines (Interface), So It would lead to Inconsistency and debugging difficulty